# Change UIVisualEffectView Colour Beyond Light/Dark?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uivisualeffectview

Is it possible to change the colour of the `UIVisualEffectView` beyond the standard extra light, light and dark?

I need to achieve the shade between that of light and dark presets.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something similar to `UIVisualEffectView` but with more control, I recommend taking a look at Apple's `UIImageEffects` sample code.

You can find it at the [iOS Developer Library : Blurring and Tinting an Image](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UIImageEffects/Listings/UIImageEffects_UIImageEffects_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013396-UIImageEffects_UIImageEffects_h-DontLinkElementID_8)

Here's the method that may be of interest to you :

```
+ (UIImage*)imageByApplyingBlurToImage:(UIImage*)inputImage withRadius:(CGFloat)blurRadius tintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:(CGFloat)saturationDeltaFactor maskImage:(UIImage *)maskImage
```

Notice the `tintColor` and the `saturationDeltaFactor` params.

Comment: What if you don't want to tint an image, but an ordinary view?